# castShadow and recieveShadow is not rendering in the scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer

I am learning threejs by doing some games. I am able to render all models in the scene and added few lights to and it is perfect now,
but when I try to cast and recieve shadows on the plane. The shadows of the objects in scene are not rendering.

I dont understand where I am doing wrong.

Below is the code

Please have a look and help me resolving the issue.

```js
import { OrbitControls } from '../assets/js/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from '../assets/js/GLTFLoader.js';
import { OBJLoader } from '../assets/js/OBJLoader.js';
import { MTLLoader } from '../assets/js/MTLLoader.js';

const extrudeSettings = { depth: 8, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 2, steps: 2, bevelSize: 1, bevelThickness: 1 };
const logo = {
  position : {
    top: 750,
    back: -2000,
  },
  title: " Exhibition !!!",
  color: 0x006699
};

var camera, scene, renderer, man_walk, mixer, action, keyboard, controls, door, mixerG, mixerB;
var mixerW = new THREE.AnimationMixer();
var man_walk = new THREE.Scene();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
var objLoader = new OBJLoader();

init();
animate();

function init(){

  // RENDERER
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.gammaOutput = true
  renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
  renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // SCENE
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xC3D8D6 );
  // scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 0, 750 );

  // CAMERA
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
  camera.position.y = 250;
  camera.position.z = 2090;

  // LIGHTS
  const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
  light.position.set = (0,100,100);
  light.castShadow = true;
  
  scene.add(light);

  var dlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xaabbff, 0.3 );
  dlight.position.x = 0;
  dlight.position.y = 250;
  dlight.position.z = 2500;
  dlight.castShadow = true;
  scene.add( dlight );

  // KEY EVENTS
  keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
  // console.log(keyboard);

  // // ORBIT CONTROLS
  // controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  // controls.enableDampling = true;
  // controls.campingFactor = 0.25;
  // controls.enableZoom = true;

  ExhibitionLogo()
  getAlternateTiles();
  getFloorMaterialByImage();
  loadDoor();
  loadTent();
  loadSchoolGirl();
  loadCollegeBoy()
  loadMan();
  // loadIntroModel();
  loadFrame();
}

function loadDoor(){
  // objLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/Doorway/Doorway.obj', object => {
  //   object.traverse(function (child) {
  //       if (child.type == "Mesh") {
  //         child.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  //       }
  //   });
  //   door=object;
  //   scene.add(object);
  //   object.rotation.z = -Math.PI / 2;
  //   object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;

  //   object.scale.multiplyScalar(50);
  //   object.position.z = 1000
  // });
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/torii_gate/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    var door = gltf.scene;
    door.position.set(0, 250, 1050);
    door.scale.set(500,400,500);
    door.rotateY(210.5);
    scene.add(door);
  });
}

function loadMan(){
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/boy_animated/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    man_walk = gltf.scene;
    man_walk.position.set(0, 0, 2050);
    man_walk.rotateY(210.5);
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(man_walk);
    mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(man_walk);
    mixer.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]).play();
  });
}

function loadWoman(){
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/woman/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    var woman = gltf.scene;
    woman.position.set(-300, 0, -500);
    scene.add(woman);
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    mixerW = new THREE.AnimationMixer(woman);
    mixerW.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]).play();

    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(woman);
    console.log(box)
    var text1 = makeTextSprite("Hello, Welcome to  Gallery. This will take you to SOMs world");
    scene.add(text1);
    text1.position.set(-300, box.max.y + 20, -500);
    text1.scale.set(150,100,1);
  });
}

function loadTent(){
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/single_edition_tent/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    var tent = gltf.scene;
    tent.rotateY(10);
    tent.scale.set(130,120,100);
    tent.position.set(-300, 0, -900);
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(tent);
    // generateCircleStage(extrudeSettings);
    generateHexagonStage(extrudeSettings, -300, -900);
  });
  loadWoman();
}

function loadSchoolGirl() {
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/girl_idle/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    gltf.scene.position.set(-1300, 100, 0);
    gltf.scene.rotateY(10);
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    gltf.scene.scale.multiplyScalar(60);
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    mixerG = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
    mixerG.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]).play();
  });
}

function loadCollegeBoy() {
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/levi_boy_stylish/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    gltf.scene.position.set(60, 0, 60)
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    gltf.scene.scale.multiplyScalar(50);
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    mixerB = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
    mixerB.clipAction(gltf.animations[0]).play();
  });
}

function loadIntroModel() {
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/cute_boy/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(gltf.scene);
    gltf.scene.position.z = (box.max.z - box.min.z) / 2;
    gltf.scene.position.x = -(box.max.x - box.min.x) / 2;
    gltf.scene.position.y = 50;
    
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    gltf.scene.scale.multiplyScalar(30);
  });
}

function loadFrame() {
  gltfLoader.load('/assets/3d_models/photo/scene.gltf', gltf => {
    gltf.scene.position.set(1950, 150, -600)
    gltf.scene.scale.multiplyScalar(200);
    gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
      if (child.type == "Mesh") {
          var newTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '/assets/img/man.jpg' );
          newTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
          newTexture.flipY = false;
          child.material.map = newTexture;
          child.material.needsUpdate = true;
          child.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
    gltf.scene.rotateY(100);
    gltf.scene.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
  });
}

// Animate
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
  var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta; 
  mixerW.update(delta);
  mixerG.update(delta*5);
  mixerB.update(delta*5);
  render();
  updateMan();
}

function updateMan(){

  var delta = clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
  var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta; 
  mixerW.update(delta);
  var moveDistance = 550 * delta; // 100 pixels per second
  var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second
  
  if ( keyboard.pressed("a") ){
      man_walk.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
  }
  if ( keyboard.pressed("d") ){
      man_walk.rotateOnAxis(new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
  } 
  if ( keyboard.pressed("w") ){
      man_walk.translateZ(moveDistance);
      mixer.update(delta*5);
  } 
  if ( keyboard.pressed("s") ){
      man_walk.translateZ(-moveDistance);
      mixer.update(delta*5);
  }
  var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,220,-600);
  var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4( man_walk.matrixWorld );
  camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
  camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
  camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
  camera.lookAt(man_walk.position);
}

function render() 
{
    // controls.update();
 renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

/********************************** START : FLOOR *************************************/
function getAlternateTiles() {
  var segments = 50;
  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(5000, 5000, segments, segments);
  geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
  var materialEven = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x85A95D});
  var materialOdd = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x93BC54});
  
  // #485C64
  var materials = [materialEven, materialOdd];
  
  for(var x=0; x<segments; x++) {
      for(var y=0; y<segments; y++) {
          var i = x * segments + y;
          var j = 2 * i;
          geometry.faces[ j ].materialIndex = geometry.faces[ j + 1 ].materialIndex = (x + y) % 2;
      }
  }
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materials);
  mesh.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(mesh);
}

function getFloorMaterialByImage() {
  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 500, 5000, 10, 10 );
  geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );
  // lightwood.jpg, whitetiles.jpg, floorline.jpg, woodsheet.jpg, Carpet.jpeg, Wood_Bamboo.jpeg, corporate.jpg
  var floorTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( '/assets/img/corporate.jpg' );
  floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  floorTexture.repeat.set(500, 500);
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: floorTexture});

  // Vertical road
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  mesh.position.set(0,0.2,0);
  mesh.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(mesh);

  // Horizontal road
  var mesh1 = mesh.clone();
  mesh1.rotateY(Math.PI / 2);
  mesh1.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(mesh1);


  //cube
  var geometry1 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 3, 10 );//#8B0000
  var material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x8B0000} );
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1 );
  cube.scale.set(150,10,100);
  cube.position.set(0,1,-2000);

  var geometry2 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 3, 10 );//#8B0000
  var material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x191970} );
  var cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
  cube2.scale.set(100,10,150);
  cube2.position.set(2000,0,0);

  var geometry3 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 10, 3, 10 );//#8B0000
  var material3 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x006400} );
  var cube3 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry3, material3 );
  cube3.scale.set(100,10,150);
  cube3.position.set(-2000,0,0);

  cube.receiveShadow = true;
  cube2.receiveShadow = true;
  cube3.receiveShadow = true;

  scene.add(cube2);
  scene.add(cube3);
  scene.add( cube );
}
/********************************** END : FLOOR *************************************/

/********************************** START :  GALLERY LOGO *************************************/
function ExhibitionLogo() {
  var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
  loader.load( '/assets/font/gentilis_bold.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
    var xMid, text;

    var matDark = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( {
      color: logo.color,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    } );

    var matLite = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
      color: logo.color,
      transparent: true,
      opacity: 0.4,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    } );

    var shapes = font.generateShapes( logo.title, 1000 );
    var geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry( shapes );
    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    xMid = - 0.5 * ( geometry.boundingBox.max.x - geometry.boundingBox.min.x );
    geometry.translate( xMid, 0, 0 );

    text = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, matLite );
    text.position.z = logo.position.back;
    text.position.y = logo.position.top;
    scene.add( text );

    var lineText = new THREE.Object3D();
    for ( var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i ++ ) {
      var shape = shapes[ i ];
      var points = shape.getPoints();
      var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints( points );
      geometry.translate( xMid, logo.position.top, 0 );
      var lineMesh = new THREE.Line( geometry, matDark );
      lineText.add( lineMesh );
      lineText.position.z = logo.position.back + 50;
    }

    scene.add( lineText );
  });
}
/********************************** END :  GALLERY LOGO *************************************/

/********************************** START : TEXT TO SHOW WHEN USER APPROACHES PERSONS *************************************/
function makeTextSprite(message, parameters) {
  // Canvas for text
  const textCanvas = prepareTextCanvas(message, parameters);

  // Canvas Texture
  const texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(textCanvas);
  texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
  texture.wrapS = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;
  texture.wrapT = THREE.ClampToEdgeWrapping;

  // Sprite Material
  const textMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
    map: texture,
    transparent: true,
  });

  // Sprite
  const textSprite = new THREE.Sprite(textMaterial);
  return textSprite;
}

function prepareTextCanvas(message, parameters) {
  if ( parameters === undefined ) parameters = {};
  var fontface = parameters.hasOwnProperty("fontface") ? parameters["fontface"] : "Calibri";
  var fontsize = parameters.hasOwnProperty("fontsize") ? parameters["fontsize"] : 16;
  var borderThickness = parameters.hasOwnProperty("borderThickness") ? parameters["borderThickness"] : 4;
  var borderColor = parameters.hasOwnProperty("borderColor") ?parameters["borderColor"] : "white";
  var backgroundColor = parameters.hasOwnProperty("backgroundColor") ?parameters["backgroundColor"] : "blue";
  var textColor = parameters.hasOwnProperty("textColor") ?parameters["textColor"] : "white";

  var maxWidth = 280;
  var lineHeight = 20;
  
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = (canvas.width - maxWidth) / 2; // default canvas width-300, height-150
  var y = 35;
  context.font = fontsize + "px " + fontface;
  context.fillStyle   = backgroundColor;
  context.strokeStyle = borderColor;
  context.lineWidth = borderThickness;
  context.fillRect(0, 15, canvas.width, lineHeight + y); 
  context.fillStyle = textColor;

  wrapText(context, message, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight);
  return context.canvas;
}

function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var line = '';
  for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      line = words[n] + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    }
    else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  context.fillText(line, x, y);
}
/************************************* END : TEXT TO SHOW WHEN USER APPROACHES PERSONS *************************************/

/************************************* START : HEXAGON STAGES *************************************/
function generateHexagonStage(extrudeSettings, x, z) {
  generate3DHexagon(100, extrudeSettings, 0x00f000, x, 8, z)
  generate3DHexagon(80, extrudeSettings, 0xff00ff, x, 16, z)
  generate3DHexagon(60, extrudeSettings, 0x00f000, x, 24, z)
}

function generate3DHexagon(size, extrudeSettings, color, x, y, z) {
  var hexShape = getHexagonShape(size);
  var hexagon = getHexagonMesh(hexShape, extrudeSettings, color, x, y, z)
  scene.add(hexagon);
}

function getHexagonMesh(shape, extrudeSettings, color, x, y, z) {
  var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: color } ) );
  mesh.position.set( x, y, z - 75 );
  mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
  return mesh;
}

function getHexagonShape(cellSize) {
  // create base shape used for building geometry
  var i, verts = [];
  // create the skeleton of the hex
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    verts.push(createVertex(i, cellSize));
  }
  // copy the verts into a shape for the geometry to use
  var cellShape = new THREE.Shape();
  cellShape.moveTo(verts[0].x, verts[0].y);
  for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    cellShape.lineTo(verts[i].x, verts[i].y);
  }
  cellShape.lineTo(verts[0].x, verts[0].y);
  cellShape.autoClose = true;
  return cellShape
}

function createVertex(i, cellSize) {
  var angle = (Math.PI * 2 / 6) * i;
  return new THREE.Vector3((cellSize * Math.cos(angle)), (cellSize * Math.sin(angle)), 0);
}
/************************************* END : HEXAGON STAGES *************************************/

/************************************* START : CIRCLE STAGES *************************************/
function generateCircleStage(extrudeSettings) {
  generate3DCircle(100, extrudeSettings, 0x00f000, 8)
  generate3DCircle(80, extrudeSettings, 0xffffff, 16)
  generate3DCircle(60, extrudeSettings, 0x00f000, 24)
}

function generate3DCircle(radius, extrudeSettings, color, y) {
  var circleShape = getCircleShape(radius);
  var circle = getCircleMesh( circleShape, extrudeSettings, color, 0, y, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 );
  circle.rotation.x = Math.PI/2;
  scene.add(circle);
}

function getCircleMesh( shape, extrudeSettings, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s ) {

  // extruded shape
  var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );

  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: color } ) );
  mesh.position.set( x, y, z - 75 );
  mesh.rotation.set( rx, ry, rz );
  // mesh.scale.set( s, s, s );
  return mesh
}

function getCircleShape(radius) {
  var circleShape = new THREE.Shape()
    .moveTo( 0, radius )
    .quadraticCurveTo( radius, radius, radius, 0 )
    .quadraticCurveTo( radius, - radius, 0, - radius )
    .quadraticCurveTo( - radius, - radius, - radius, 0 )
    .quadraticCurveTo( - radius, radius, 0, radius );
  return circleShape
}
/************************************* END : CIRCLE STAGES *************************************/
```

Please find the full code from here:

https://github.com/chintuyadavsara/threejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested your code offline and there are multiple issue and runtime errors:

- `AmbientLight` does not cast shadows. Setting `castShadow` will produce a runtime error.
- You have not configured the shadow frustum for your instance of `DirectionalLight` correctly. Try it with this code:

```js
var dlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xaabbff, 0.3 );
dlight.position.x = 0;
dlight.position.y = 750;
dlight.position.z = 0;
dlight.castShadow = true;
dlight.shadow.camera.top = 2500;
dlight.shadow.camera.bottom = - 2500;
dlight.shadow.camera.left = - 2500;
dlight.shadow.camera.right = 2500;
dlight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
dlight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;
dlight.shadow.mapSize.set( 2048, 2048 );
```

- A loaded `glTF` asset does not cast shadows if you just set `gltf.scene.castShadow` to `true`. You have to do this for recursively for all meshes.

```js
gltf.scene.traverse( function ( object ) {

    if ( object.isMesh ) object.castShadow = true;

} );
```

- The paths to your assets in the GitHub repository are wrong. E.g. instead of `/assets/3d_models/torii_gate/scene.gltf` it should be `../assets/3d_models/torii_gate/scene.gltf`.
- There are some deprecation warnings logged in the browser console. I suggest you configure the renderer like so (also probably don't change the default shadow map type):

```js
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
```

- Since `MeshBasicMaterial` is an unlit material, it can't receive shadows. That means you should use e.g. `MeshPhongMaterial` for your tiles and floors otherwise you won't see any shadows.

Comment: Thank you so much, yes, somehow i forgot that Ambient light does not cast shadows.

Comment: I did the same thing you did and still did not get the shadows, may be because of the warning. my bad. After changing the render settings suggested by you, its working now